# How to add Java 11 on Dockerfile?

Tags: java, docker

I am trying to make a Dockerfile where Java11 has to be "loaded".

However, when I try:

```
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:linuxuprising/java
```

then I get this error:

> /bin/sh: 1: add-apt-repository: not found
>   The command '/bin/sh -c add-apt-repository -y ppa:linuxuprising/java' returned a non-zero code: 127

My question is how could I "install" Java11 on Docker?

Comment: Not sure about the context, but check this out: https://dzone.com/articles/creating-a-docker-image-with-ubuntu-and-java

Comment: You can use the Java 11 image from hub.docker.com by typing the command :docker pull openjdk:tag on your machines terminal, where the tag is version of your intended java version. Or you can simply specify the image on your Dockerfile where FROM attribute must be the version of java.

Comment: @dipoisola I used to do the same thing, but for Java11 it doesn t work..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that is not possible to base your image on a [OpenJDK *official* image](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk).

Take a look to how it is installed in the *official* image [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/master/11/jdk/buster/Dockerfile) (or the [repository](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/tree/master/11)).

There are also alternatives images, like [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot) ([Dockerfile](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker/blob/master/11/jdk/ubuntu/Dockerfile.hotspot.releases.full) based on Ubuntu)

Comment: Hi Gonzalo and thanks for the help. However, I am not able to base my image on the official.. I will try to make it happen after what you said.

Comment: I would really prefer having "FROM Ubuntu" in my Dockerfile. Do you think there is a way to do that? Sorry for the inconvenience but I am really new to this technology! Thanks again!

Comment: There are AdoptOpenJDK images based on Ubuntu -> https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker/blob/master/11/jdk/ubuntu/Dockerfile.hotspot.releases.full

Comment: Dead links 12345

Comment: your second link is outdated, is that Dockerfile still publicly available somewhere? I need to install it on a ubuntu base, so I can't use the official base image

Comment: Updated Dockerfile link, seems that when they added some variants of the image, they modified the directory structure.

Comment: links are dead again

Answer (score 7):

For CentOS in your docker image you still can use:

```
FROM centos
RUN yum install -y java-11
```

Answer (score 4):

Your specific error you were receiving is because `software-properties-common` is not installed.

So make sure you do the following before `add-apt-repository -y ppa:linuxuprising/java`:

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y software-properties-common
```